# Physical KASLR disabled: no suitable memory region

Tags: linux, build, kernel, boot

I built and installed the latest Kernel (v5.4) from source (downloaded from Linux repo). I followed the steps explained here:

https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-26.html

I used `make menuconfig` but did not make any change to default values. After doing all steps, I rebooted but got this error on a black screen in boot time:

> Physical KASLR disabled: no suitable memory region!

I`m using ubuntu 19.10 with deafult Kernel 5.3.0-23-generic.

Here is some info and sth I did to solve thie problem:

```
> cat /boot/config-5.3.0-23-generic | grep CONFIG_RANDOMIZE_BASE=y
CONFIG_RANDOMIZE_BASE=y

> cat /boot/config-5.4.0+ | grep CONFIG_RANDOMIZE_BASE=y
CONFIG_RANDOMIZE_BASE=y
```

I changed the Grub according to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1000525/kaslr-disabled-could-not-find-suitable-e820-region but nothing happened.

Here is my first experience in building the kernel. I`d really appreciate it if you could help me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a virtual machine I would suggest looking at your system ram settings and make sure its configured to have at least 1024mb of ram.